# How to do an "OR" when requiring a Gem version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

Currently I have a Gemspec that requires a specific version of Rails 3.x with Rails > 3.1:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # (...)
  s.add_dependency "railties", "~> 3.1"
  # (...)
end
```

I am looking to update this statement to require `~> 3.1` OR `~> 4.0.0`. I had tried already:

- `~> 3.1, ~> 4.0.0`
- `~> 3.1 OR ~> 4.0.0`
- `~> 3.1 || ~> 4.0.0`
- `~> 3.1 ~> 4.0.0`

None have worked. **Is that possible with the current RubyGems version?**

For now I am using > 3.1, but the real question is if that's possible.

Comment: This is an interesting requirement. Let's see if a solution will arise.

Comment: What's the condition for requiring one or the other?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I know that my Gem is compatible with ~> 3.1 (3.1.x, 3.2.x) and compatible with ~> 4.0.0 (4.0.x), but I am not sure it will work with Rails 4.1.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `~>`, it seems as if you are willing to use any version of the gem that is after 3.1, that is, any 3.x OR any 4.0.x, but not a 4.x where x is greater than 1.

If that is your intention, then according to [the rubygems guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#declaring-dependencies), you'll want to use a pattern like:

```
spec.add_dependency 'library', ['>= 3.1', '< 4.1']
```

I think it might be the addition of brackets that you need.